# Is there a command that can give me a logic query plan overview in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, sql-execution-plan

I need to practice the logic query plan writing so I was wondering If there is a command similar to EXPLAIN, that can give a Logic Query Plan?

Example:
[image: query plan]

Comment: What's wrong with `EXPLAIN`

Comment: I want it as the image above

Comment: There is nothing in the database that can do that; perhaps there are some tools that generate a graphical execution plan, but it probably won't look the way you want it.